# no matching function to call QLinEdit

Tags: c++, qt

I'm new to qt.I'm making a calculator, I made a function to add 2 numbers but its giving me some weird errors. The function first takes input as 2 `strings` from `lineEdit` and the converts them to `int` by `toInt` function and adds them then puts it in a `label` by `text().My function`:

```
void calculator::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    ui->ansLabel->setText("+");
    ui->firstNo->text(string1);
    ui->secondNo->text(string2);
    int firstno = string1.toInt();
    int secondno = string2.toInt();
    int ans = firstno + secondno;
    ui->ansLabel->setText(ans);
}
```

Errors:

```
    \Calculator\calculator.cpp:20: error: no matching function for call to 'QLineEdit::text(QString&)'
     ui->firstNo->text(string1);
\Calculator\calculator.cpp:25: error: invalid user-defined conversion from 'int' to 'const QString&' [-fpermissive]
     ui->ansLabel->setText(ans);
                              ^
\Calculator\calculator.cpp:25: error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'const char*' [-fpermissive]
     ui->ansLabel->setText(ans);
                          ^
```

How to fix these errors. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler tells you exactly what is wrong. According to the Qt documentation, `QLineEdit::text()` function doesn't accept any argument, but returns a value. In the same way, `QLabel::setText()` does not accept integer as an argument, but `QString`. Thus, you need to write your function like this:

```
void calculator::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    ui->ansLabel->setText("+");
    QString string1 = ui->firstNo->text();
    QString string2 = ui->secondNo->text();
    int firstno = string1.toInt();
    int secondno = string2.toInt();
    int ans = firstno + secondno;
    ui->ansLabel->setText(QString::number(ans));
}
```